# ¿Cómo seleccionar todos los resultados de una tabla y combinar sus atributos que están en otra tabla?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo dos tablas, una de clientes, otra de atributos

```
t1(clientes)
id
nombre
....

t2(atributos)
id
id_ref
key
value
```

Lo que quiero es seleccionar todos los registros de los clientes, pero estos clientes tienen sucursales diferentes que estoy almacenando como atributo en la tabla 2, quiero poder seleccionar cada cliente y sus sucursales, así sea 1 o más.

He intentado con este query, pero obviamente devuelve información duplicada.

```
 SELECT
    clientes.id,
    clientes.razonSocial,
    clientes.nombre,
    clientes.rfc,
    clientes.email,
    clientes.direccion,
    clientes.telefono,
    clientes.cuerpo,
    clientes.fecha,
    clientes.borrado,
    COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(atributos.value SEPARATOR '|'), "Sin sucursal") AS sucursales
FROM
    clientes
INNER JOIN atributos ON clientes.id = atributos.id_ref
```

Eso me devuelve resultados, pero solo de los que tienen una sucursal, quisiera que regresen resultados haya o no sucursal registrada en tabla 2.

Comparto el query, si alguien pudiera ayudarme a mejorarlo se lo agradecería mucho:

```
SELECT
    clientes.id,
    clientes.nombre,
    COALESCE((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(atributos.value SEPARATOR "|") FROM atributos WHERE clientes.id = atributos.id_ref), "Sin sucursal") AS sucursales
FROM
clientes
```

Comment: si no quieres la información duplicada, entonces cómo quieres obtener los resultados cuando hay más de una sucursal?

Comment: Debe ser posible, una alternativa es usando GROUP_CONCAT, pero no sé si sea la más adecuada.

Comment: ah, no me refería a si es posible o no...literalmente estaba preguntando cómo quieres obtener los resultados, o sea, si tienes un ejemplo de cuál es el resultado deseado

Comment: Oh, en estos momentos me funciona mucho con GROUP_CONCAT usando un serparador como | o similar y solo dividirlos con un explode() posteriormente, o no sé si exista alguna forma de generar un array dentro de una columna, talvez un JSON.

Comment: Lo logré al parecer, edito y comparto el query.